# COCOS2D spotlight icon not showing on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocos2d-iphone

I have just created a new set of icons  and added them to my project. While everything works in the simulator, including iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

When I run my game on my iPhone 6, the spotlight icon is still the COCOS2D icon.

Any ideas why it works in the simulator but not on the device?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: The simulator is not a device. For example, sim file names are not case sensitive but devices are. Could be that. Xcode/simulator have all sorts of caches, so a resource could be 'present' on sim but not in your resources folder. Could be that too. etc.

Comment: and do try deleting the app from the device/simulator whenever a change is seemingly not applied

Comment: @LearnCocos2D along with half-a-dozen other cabalistic rituals that will evolve with each new version of xcode. But the one you point out is true since my first day on apple's hIDEous.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried cleaning the build, deleting off my phone and re-compiling, but still no luck. I am using the asset manager rather than naming, could this be the reason?

Comment: not certain if this is still present in xcode 6, clean build folder. If (with asset manager) you can delete the icon, do that, clean build folder, re-add the texture, delete the app from both the simulator and device, then build and launch on device.

Comment: Updated my phone to IOS 8.1 and it worked fine. Looks like a bug in IOS 8

Comment: hahaha ... oh well. You should post that as an answer and accept it so that other victims can benefit from yet another gem gem.

Comment: Cabalistic rituals are the cornerstone of becoming a master programmer. Every full moon I run a "count all lines" script over every source code I've ever written, then print out the number in Courier New 64 point, hang the piece of paper on a thread and at precisely 1 AM light it on fire while bunny-hopping around it in circles, shouting "GOO GOL!" ten times consecutively. Everything works better after that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated to the latest version of IOS 8 and this solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to power down your iPhone/device and restart it.

My guess would be that it only builds the cache of images when the phone starts. This may not be the case for a proper app installed from the proper app store.

I had the same issue, where my main icon worked, but the spotlight was still the empty-square from Xcode. Regardless of how many times I cleaned/rebuilt/deleted the app.